# localhost not loading Ubuntu GUI on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 machine yesterday. I set up Ubuntu with WSL and Remote Desktop Connection using xrdp.

Everything cool but when I start the Remote Desktop Connection, the localhost window is not loading the Ubuntu GUI...what am I doing wrong? I watched tutorials all day yesterday and did everything step by step..I have the Ubuntu terminal, but my goal is to have the GUI running along with my Windows.

This is what I see when I run the Remote Desktop Connection: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Rx2.jpg

After this blue screen it should load the Ubuntu GUI, but it's not loading it...

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: You mean you don't get the user / password prompt? Probably there is something wrong with the xrdp configuration.

Comment: WSL is not intended to run GUI applications or a desktop environment.  Wrong tool for the job.  Install Ubuntu in a VM if you want a desktop experience. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04. I did manage to set up the GUI but I think there are errors..I installed firefox with the panel, but when I go about opening the browser, it's not loading. Also, I am unable to adjust the sound, as well as when I run the server and launch the Remote Desktop Connection, the Ubuntu GUI is not loading every time. I was also advised not to use WSL but to download Ubuntu from their official website, as well as a VM from vm.org and set it up this way, just like you said in your comment, Nmath.

Comment: As I said above, I managed to set up and run Ubuntu. Everything was cool and I even wrote some commands in the panel, but after a while, Ubuntu not loading when the Remote Desktop Connection started: https://imgur.com/a/sJNUr8J

Comment: how can I reset everything I configed in the PowerShell in order to install Ubuntu in a VM freshly?